# Property 'flat' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use `flat()` in a typescript script. The target in my tsconfig.json is set to `es2017` and I defined an interface for the input variable.
But I do get the error `Property 'flat' does not exist on type '{ type: string; source: string; target: string; }[][]'`

Could anyone explain why this problem occurs?

```
interface Dependencies {
  [key: string]: Array<{
    type: string
    source: string
    target: string
  }>
}
function example(deps: Dependencies) {
  const result = Object
    .values(deps) // Property 'flat' does not exist on type '{ type: string; source: string; target: string; }[][]'
    .flat()

  return result
}
const dependencies = {
  'foo': [
    {
      type: 'static',
      source: 'source',
      target: 'target'
    }
  ]
}
example(dependencies)
```

Comment: `flat` was added in `ES2019` https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L52

Answer (score 2):

`flat` was added in ES2019

[ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.flat)
[Typescript definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L52)

Comment: I changed compiler options `"target": "es2019"`, but still the same error

Comment: I was having the same issue after I changed the target to es2019, I rebuilt my app and the error went away

Comment: Here's working example with target `ES2019` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/NoXQdAZgNghgLgCgJQG4g